# 404 on requests without trailing slash to i18n urls

Tags: python, django

Because of the `APPEND_SLASH = True` setting all requests with "/whatever/path" will be redirected to "/whatever/path/".

BUT urls definded within a `i18n_patterns()` don't redirect for some reason

even the test works:

```
./runtests.py --settings=test_sqlite i18n.URLRedirectWithoutTrailingSlashTests
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

it doesn't work properly if the middleware's aren't in order.

see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

that's how it should look like:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   ...
)
```

Comment: This also solve problem for me. +1. Also it does not work with out localeMiddleware.